# How to create a hanging bullet list in ConTeXt

Tags: lists, context

The only way I have found seems somewhat hackish:

```
\setupitemize[leftmargin=-18pt]

\starttext

\startitemize
  \item one
  \item two
\stopitemize

body text
\stoptext
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `\setupitemize[inmargin]`.